# "Appreciate" or "Value" or...?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

Which one of the following words work better in my self-made sentences below:

> **1)** Life is too short and you're young only once. So.................your age/youth.

a) appreciate 
b) value

> **2)** ...............your parents. You may lose them someday.

a) appreciate 
b) value

I wonder if you could introduce a better option if exists for this sense.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct, however, if we look at the following definitions there is one which fits better than the other:

- **Appreciate** to recognize how good someone or something is and to value him, her, or it
- **Value** the importance or worth of something for someone

**Appreciate** your youth/parents.

Value would imply that they have worth, whereas appreciate implies you recognize that worth.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much @Bee. I waited for a long time to receive a response to this question. Just one more question. Do these two sentences sound natural to you? As a native speaker, would a native speaker phrase and utter such meanings in the way I did?

Comment: Yes both sound natural to me as a native BrE Speaker. I both value and appreciate both my youth and parents.